# In shell, how to process this line, in order to extract the filed that I want

Tags: shell

I have some lines in a plat file. Take 2 line for instance:

```
1 aa bb 05 may 2014 cc G 14-MAY-2014 hello world
j  sd  az 20140505    sd  G 14-MAY-2014 hello world haha
```

So maybe you have noticed, I can count neither the number of the char, nor the number of the space, because the lines are not well aligned, and the forth field, sometimes it's like `20140505`, sometimes it's like `05 may 2014`. So what I want, is to try to match the `G` , or match the `14-MAY-2014`. Then I can easily get the following fields: `hello world` or `hello world haha`. So Can anyone help me? thank you!

Comment: Now I use echo  ${ligne##*G} to get the field after 'G'. but This field can be 'C' or 'G'. so how to do like echo  ${ligne##*(G|C)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your lines are in a file called `test.txt`:

```
 cat test.txt | sed -r 's/^.*-[0-9]{4}\s//'
```

This is using GNU sed on a Linux system. There are many other ways. Here i simply remove anything up to and including the date from the begiining of the line.

```
sed -r 's/^.*-[0-9]{4}\s//'

-r = extendes reg ex, makes things like the quantor {4} possible
's/ ... //' = s is for substitute, 
              it matches the first part and replaces it with the second.
              since the resocond part is empty, it's a remove/delete
^  = start of line
.* = any character, any number of times
-[0-9]{4} = a dash, followed by four digits ([0-9]), the year part of the date
\s = any white space
```

Comment: @ZHE.ZHAO the answer was extended to include some explanation

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work, i'm a freshman in shell. Suppose that now i have already this line in a variable, $line...I tried to match ' G ', and cut off the following fields

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of lookbehind regex of perl:

```
perl -lne '/(?<=14-MAY-2014)(.*)/ && print $1' file
```

It will print anything after 14-MAY-2014.

You can also use grep if it supports -P:

```
grep -Po '(?<=14-MAY-2014)(.*)'  file
```